# HTML/JS How to input text and have it appear on screen

Tags: javascript, html

So, all I'm trying to do is have an input box into which the user types text, and when it is submitted the text appears on screen. I think I am nearly there, but I'm having a problem: the text appears on screen for a split-second and then disappears. Below is the relevant HTML:

```
<h1 id="outputtext"></h1>
<div id="box">
    <form onsubmit="f()">
        <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter text" autocapitalize="off" />
        <input type="submit" id="submitbutton">
    </form>
</div>
```

And the internal JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function f() {
    var t = document.getElementById("input").value;
    document.getElementById("outputtext").innerHTML = t;
}
</script>
```

Like I said, the entered text appears for a split-second and then disappears. Any thoughts on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. I'm sorry if this is a foolish question, but I am only a beginner, and this is my first experience with input boxes. I have searched this forum and other regions of the Web and cannot find any helpful content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hidden div shows and disappears in a flash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299401/hidden-div-shows-and-disappears-in-a-flash)

Comment: Add `return false;` to the end of your `f()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your event is onsubmit, after executing f(), the page is reloading. To avoit that, add an event parameter to your f function and call `preventDefault();` on it.

Also instead of adding event Handler to your object througt html attributes, prefer using [addEventListener](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp) on your html object.

Here is a code sample without jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function f(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var t = document.getElementById("input").value;
   document.getElementById("outputtext").innerHTML = t;
}
document.getElementById("yourform").addEventListener("submit", f);
</script>
```

**Note:** You need to add an ID (like `id="yourform"`) to your form element.
Also in order to avoid some loading issues, add your script tag to the end of your page, before `</body>`.

Edit:
My bad, I wrote `document.getElementById("yourform").addEventListener("click", f);`
 instead of `document.getElementById("yourform").addEventListener("submit", f);`

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to make the text appear, there is no need to create a form to submit. Just remove the form and put the `f()` function to the button's `onclick` event. Your javascript function is okay.

```js
function f() {
  var t = document.getElementById("input").value;
  document.getElementById("outputtext").innerHTML = t;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="outputtext"></h1>
<div id="box">
  <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter text" autocapitalize="off" />
  <button onclick="f()" type="button" id="submitbutton">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the form, it displays the output and then the page gets reloaded. Thats why you see it just for a split second. Possible solution would be to include a `return false` at the end of your `f ()` function definition.

Answer (score 0):

Another **jQuery** alternative: instead of calling an onsubmit method, just use a click function:

```
<-- jQuery CDN --> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var t;
        $('#submitbutton').click(function() {
            t = $('#input').val();
            $('#outputtext').text(t);   
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<h1 id="outputtext"></h1>
<div id="box">
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter text" autocapitalize="off" />
        <input type="submit" id="submitbutton">
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the jquery submit function here. Try this one below.
HTML:

```
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
      alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
      event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

**Note:** load first the jquery cdn before the `</body>` tag.

Answer (score -1):

What .....no....no.no
All you do is do want is text to appear on screen but it will disappeare because you need php inventory where it would be stored so the text it will disappeare always when you reload site so what you need is action button just put button on left and that make it like protected

Comment: It's clear in the question that the text disappears without reloading the page.